# WebDriverWait wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(by)) not working with Selenium 3.4.0

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timoutInSeconds);
List<WebElement> elements = 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(by));
```

Its a maven project, I have upgraded to selenium 3.4.0 version from 2.53.0 and added dependency of guava with 21.0 version.
Earlier all waits were working. When upgraded to latest selenium 3.4.0 version, all waits are breaking. Below error is received when executed tests.

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.until(Ljava/util/function/Function;)Ljava/lang/Object;

Many users says adding Guava dependency this issue no longer exists, But I am seeing this issue even after adding Guava dependency.

Comment: Here is the maven dependencies added <dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>21.0</version>
      </dependency>
</dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
 <dependencies>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

Comment: 1) Did you run `mvn clean` first? 2) Post your entire `pom.xml` - and **not** in the comments, but edit your original post.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the third comment in this one [WebDriverWait.until no longer available in Selenium-java-3.2 and Selenium-java-3.3 releases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43179497/webdriverwait-until-no-longer-available-in-selenium-java-3-2-and-selenium-java-3/43768338#43768338)

I added the guava dependency + now using fluent wait and it's working fine

Comment: I tried that its not working. Added Guava dependency and updated code as below still the error is same.   

Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
          .withTimeout(timoutInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

      WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
        public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
          return driver.findElement(by);
        }
      });

Comment: Also tried this. Still same error
final WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>() {
   @Override
   public WebElement apply(
     final WebDriver d) {
    WebElement weReturn = null;
    final WebElement bodyText = driver.findElement(by);
    if (bodyText != null) {
     weReturn = bodyText;
    }
    return weReturn;
   }
  });